# Map Amazon S3 bucket to User on website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to map s3 bucket to a user account on some website ?

For example , I have a website example.com and there is a registered user on website "john@example.com".
I also have a bucket on Amazon S3.Now what I want to know is that does a way exist where i can just map john  to his own S3 bucket so that he can upload download his documents without other users accessing his bucket ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create restriction for the AWS users. There is no way to restrict based on users in other website. At most what you can do is to create AWS users to that account with limited access(IAM) and allow only on particular part on S3 bucket for that user.